# How to check for NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, numberformatexception

I want to calculate the average of grades, now I have the basics and the layout. When the `EditText` is left open it throws a `NumberFormatException`. Can someone explain me how to check for this?

Any tips etc. are welcome!

P.S. my `EditText` are set to NumberDecimal, so I have no 'wrong input' type.

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView); 
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average); 
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton); 
final Button addGradeButton = findViewById(R.id.addGradeButton)

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
    @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")                                                     
    public void onClick(View v) { 

        double grade[]  = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weight[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weightTotal = weight[0]; double sum = grade[0] * weight[0] 

        double average = sum / weightTotal 

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String averageResult = String.format(%.2f, average);

        averageView.setText(averageText + " " + averageResult);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a try-catch block?

Comment: Thanks for the response , no I haven't tried try-cath blocks, I don't know how to work with them. Could you maybe explain how to try it out with my code?

Comment: Give [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) a read. If you have issues getting that to work you can post a question with your specific issues.

Comment: Could you post your layout too?

Comment: What you really should try is *disable the button* until both edittexts have values

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning Thanks for the suggestion it worked perfectly! Maybe you want to answer?

Comment: I just pointed you in the right direction, you solved it yourself. Just be careful of using `try` to sweep errors under the rug; if you find yourself using them constantly that might be a sign that there is some bigger underlying issues that need dealing with. Like others have suggested, preemptive validation is preferred over exception catching when possible.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning Thanks I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Always validate user input. Any input provided by a user should be untrusted until you have validated it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your error condititions before attempting to do the thing that creates the error

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView); 
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average); 
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton); 
final Button addGradeButton = findViewById(R.id.addGradeButton)

EditText[] grades = new EditText[] {
    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)
};
EditText[] weights = new EditText[] {
    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight1)
};

calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {   
    @Override                                               
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        String grade1 = grades[0].getText().toString();
        String weight1 = weights[0].getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(grade1) || TextUtils.isEmpty(weight1)) {
            return; // TODO: Show some error
        }

        double sum = Double.parseDouble(grade1) * Double.parseDouble(weight1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a "try - catch" to manage the exception like this.

```
try {
   double grade = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberanswer)).getText().toString());
   answer.setText("" + grade);
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert a number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've completed it with a "try-catch" statement, this catches the NumberFormatException every time when a field is left open.

```
final TextView averageView = findViewById(R.id.averageView); 
final String averageText = getString(R.string.average); 
final Button calculateButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateAverageButton); 
final Button addGradeButton = findViewById(R.id.addGradeButton)

calaculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() { 
    @SupressLint("SetTextI18n")                                                     
    public void onClick(View v) { 

       try {
        double grade[]  = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.grade1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weight[] = {Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight1)).getText().toString()); 

        double weightTotal = weight[0]; double sum = grade[0] * weight[0] 

        double average = sum / weightTotal 

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String averageResult = String.format(%.2f, average);

        averageView.setText(averageText + " " + averageResult);
      { catch (NumberFormatException e) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is a empty field!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
```